# Wireshark Error when starting capture

Tags: 14.04, wireshark

I'm using Wireshark on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have it up and running. However, when I click start after selecting an interface, the program freezes. 
I have tried 'export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0' with no result. 
I ran it in the terminal and this is what I got and as you can see, the errors simply repeat until I force the program to close:

```
OBJECT (object)' failed
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_name: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET      (widget)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GObject'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkRange'
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_range_get_adjustment: assertion 'GTK_IS_RANGE (range)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkOrientable'
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_orientable_get_orientation: assertion 'GTK_IS_ORIENTABLE (orientable)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkScrollbar'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GObject'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_name: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GObject'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkRange'
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_range_get_adjustment: assertion 'GTK_IS_RANGE (range)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkOrientable'
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_orientable_get_orientation: assertion 'GTK_IS_ORIENTABLE (orientable)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkScrollbar'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GObject'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_name: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GObject'
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkRange'
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_range_get_adjustment: assertion 'GTK_IS_RANGE (range)' failed
(wireshark:3669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkOrientable'
(wireshark:3669): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_orientable_get_orientation: assertion 'GTK_IS_ORIENTABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

export `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0` that works for me